# Proving $1 + 1 = 2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

How do you break down the theory of $1 + 1 = 2$? 
How do you provide a proof, please be precise. This is for one of my discrete math courses and I don't know how this is relevant to the course. And remember, please be detailed and precise.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243049/how-do-i-convince-someone-that-11-2-may-not-necessarily-be-true

Comment: It took Russell and Whitehead over 600 pages to prove this.  See Arthur Fischer's comment at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/348889/18398

Comment: "The above proposition is occasionally useful." http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/data/uploads/2010/11/principia_83_lg2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

For a problem like this, it is essential to state what the definitions of $1$ and $2$ are and what set of axioms you are using.  Using the Wikipedia Peano axioms we have $1=S(0),2=S(1), 1+1=1+S(0)=S(1+0)=S(1)=2$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{{\cal C}\ \mbox{: Cardinal}}$
$$
0={\cal C}\pars{\emptyset}\,,\quad 1={\cal C}\pars{\braces{0}}\,,\quad
2={\cal C}\pars{\braces{0,1}}={\cal C}\pars{\braces{0,0}}
$$

> $$
> 1 + 1={\cal C}\pars{\braces{0}\cup\braces{0}} = {\cal C}\pars{\braces{0,0}} = 2
> $$