# A rigorous mathematical proof of $1+1=2$.

Tags: arithmetic

Our school teacher just asked us to write the best possible proof of $1+1=2$.
First thought he was joking but he was very serious about this question.

I could not even try an attempt.

Comment: You can't prove a definition.

Comment: See _Principia Mathematica_ (where Russell and Whitehead proved $1+1=2$ in an axiomatic set-theoretical context).

Comment: Arguably the Principia Mathematica has the most thorough proof of 1+1=2.

Comment: What is the solid ground you're allowed to assume? How are $1$ and $2$ defined? I mean, assume that $1+1=2$ does not hold and show that your favorite arithmetic theorem doesn't either.

Comment: Thnx Matt and Parcly just saw that and will show the same to my teacher.

Comment: You need definitions first: how is defined '$1$'...? how is defined '$2$'...? How is defined '$+$'...? and how is defined '$=$'? Possibly the proof will follow directly from those definitions.

Comment: The notorious version is [Theorem $*54\cdot 43$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Mathematica#/media/File:Principia_Mathematica_54-43.png) of Whitehead & Russell's *Principia Mathematica* p. $360$ which then says *"From this proposition it will follow, when arithmetical addition has been defined, that $1+1=2$."*  In modern notation, you can find the proof at http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/pm54.43.html

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243049/how-do-i-convince-someone-that-11-2-may-not-necessarily-be-true) (and maybe some of the posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/243049) and perhaps also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348889/is-11-2-a-theorem).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to define what system you are working in.  In Peano Arithmetic, PA, $1$ and $2$ are not part of the language.  They are abbreviations for $S(0)$ and $S(S(0))$, where $S$ is intended as the successor function, so you are being asked to prove $S(0)+S(0)=S(S(0))$.  You can follow the [Wikipedia proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Addition), which you may need to update a bit depending on how your version of the axioms are written.  Basically this should look a lot like your axioms that define addition.