# if $x$ is odd, show that $x^3+x$ has a remainder 2 when divided by 4

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

I did part of this question but am stuck and don't know how to continue

I let $x= 2k +1$

Also noticed that $x^3+x = x(x^2+1)$

therefore
$4m+2 = 2k+1((2k+1)^2+1)$

I simplified this and ended up with

$4m+2 = 8k^3+12k^2+8k+2$

I don't know how to continue from and prove that $x^3+x$ has remainder 2 when divided by 4

Comment: $(2k+1)((2k+1)^2+1)=8 k^3 + 12 k^2 + 8 k + 2$, slightly different from what you wrote and the difference is important.

Comment: "let the divisible term and remainder be 4m+2"  Don't assume what you want to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't do your math right Let $x= 2k + 1$ so $x(x^2 + 1) = (2k+1)((2k+1)^2 + 1)=$

$(2k+1)((2k+1)^2 + 1)  = 8k^3 + 12k^2 + 8k +2$ so you had a typo.

But it's easier to do

$(2k+1)^3 + (2k + 1)=$

$(2k)^3 + 3(2k)^2 + 3(2k)+ 1 + (2k + 1)=$

$8k^3 + 12k^2 + 6k + 1 + 2k + 1=$

$8k^3 + 12k^2 + 8k + 2$.

So $4|8, 12, 8$ the $4|8k^3 + 12k^2 + 8k$ and the remainder of $8k^3 + 12k^2 + 8k + 2$ is $2$.

....

Also ... this may be overly abstract:  If we let $x = 2k + 1 = m + 1$ where $m=2k$ is an even number, then $x^3 +x = (m+1)^3 + (m+1) = a_3m^3 + a_2m^2 + a_1m + a_0$, a polynomial.  For $j\ge 2; m^j = (2k)^j = 2^j*k^j=4*2^{j-2}{k^j}$ we have $4|a_jm^j$.

So the remainder when divided by $4$ will be the same as the remainder of $a_1m + a_0$.

By binomial theorem:  $(m+1)^3 = \sum_{i=0}^3 {3\choose i}m^i$ so for $(m+1)^3 + (m+ 1)$ we have $a_1 = {3\choose 1} + 1$ and $a_0 = {3\choose 0} + 1$.

${3\choose 1} = 3$ and $3+1=4$ so $4|a_jm$ and the remainder when divided by $4$ will be the same as the remainder of $a_0 = {3\choose 0} + 1$ when divided by $4$.

${3\choose 0} = 1$ and [1+1 = 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278974/prove-that-11-2)

Comment: I don't see how this is any easier but what the hell, ***+1, endorsed!!! anyway***.  Cheers!

Comment: binomial theorem is consistent.  $(2k+1)((2k+1)^2 +1)$ is a distribution of many terms tht I had a hard time keeping them straight.  Also.... well, I'll add my also to the post.

Comment: NIce work there in you addenda!

Answer (score 4):

If $x$ is odd, then $x\equiv1$ or $3\pmod4$; in the former case $x^3+x\equiv2\pmod4$, and in the latter case $x^3+x\equiv30\equiv2\pmod4.$

Answer (score 2):

$x = 2k + 1; \tag 1$

$x ^3 = 8k^3 + 12k^2 + 6k + 1; \tag 2$

$x ^3 + x =  8k^3 + 12k^2 + 6k + 1 + (2k + 1)$
$ = 8k^3 + 12k^2 + 8k +  2 = 4(2k^3 + 3k^2 + 2k)  + 2, \tag 3$

that is,

$x^3 + x \equiv 2 \mod 4, \tag 4$

which by the [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) implies the remainder of $x^3 + x$ when divided by $4$ is $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=2n+1, then
f(x)=x^3+x=(2n+1)^3+(2n+1)=2+8n^3+12n^2+8n \implies \frac{f(x)}{4}=\frac{2}{4}+2n^3+3n^2+2n.$ So the remaner is 2.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x) =x^3+x-2$ instead. This can be factorised as $(x-1)(x^2+x+2)$ instead using the remainder theorem ($1^3+1-2 = 0$).

If $x = 1 \pmod 2$, then $x -1 \equiv 0 \pmod 2$ and $x^2+x+2 \equiv 1^2+1+2 \equiv 4 \equiv 0 \pmod 2$. Therefore  $x^3+x-2 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$, so $x^3+x \equiv 2 \pmod 4$.

Comment: Typo: "If $x=1\pmod 2$, then $x-1≡0\pmod 2$..."