# Is there a way to prove that $2+2$ really equals $4$?

Tags: arithmetic

In elementary school, one learns that $2+2=4$ by experiment (putting two apples next to two other apples), and maybe also from some addition table to be memorized.

But is there any approach that *proves* $2+2 = 4$? If so, an example of such a proof would be good.

Comment: By the way, actually serious about this. It's not homework or anything, but I'm honestly curious. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, see [this paper](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/as2446/224.pdf) for a proof.

Comment: That's pretty cool. Thanks for finding this!

Comment: For this question to make sense you must specify what you mean by $2$, what you mean by $4$, and what you mean by $+$. Before you do that, you did not actually ask a question.

Comment: We can rigorously construct the natural numbers, as well as define what we mean by addition. Statements like $2 + 2 = 4$ can then be proved from those definitions. You may find it helpful to read about the Peano axioms.

Comment: If you start with a set of axioms for the integers, as is typically done in number theory courses, then you could certainly prove it from the axioms.  You would define $2 = 1 + 1$, then define $3 = 2 + 1$, then define $4 = 3 + 1$, then give a short proof.

Comment: If something wasn't equal to $2+2$, we usually wouldn't call it $4$.

Comment: But things that are $2 + 2$ sometimes get called $0$ or $1$.

Comment: that paper is just a joke

Comment: @IttayWeiss No, he is asking if there are definitions that allow us to prove the statement; the question makes sense as it stands.

Comment: What do you mean by "not relying on other facts of addition"?  Obviously if you can not lean on any definition of addition you can not prove that addition has any given property.

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with logic. It's also impossible to tell just from the current question. Such open-ended questions (without saying what is the language and the axioms being used) were discussed before in the "almost the same" 1+1=2 questions: [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/243049/622) and [that one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/95069/622) and [generally see this list](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/243049). If all those discussions still haven't answered your question, please clarify your question, and I will vote to reopen it.

Comment: I gave it a plus 1 because you are brave enough to ask such question. Kudos to you sir!

Comment: @AsafKaragila It may be "open ended" and vague but it has EVERYTHING to do with logic.

Comment: @SniperClown: *EVERYTHING*? Are you Gary Oldman in "Leon: The Professional"? I agree that this question has something to do with logic. But here's the kicker, when you ask a question about proving $f'$ doesn't exist when $f$ is not continuous, does it have to do with logic? Of course, but it's not tagged as [logic] (certainly not as the only tag) because there is a natural context to it. So I expect questions tagged under [logic] to have reasonably defined context to them, to prevent 8 answers of pure guesswork. So let me ask differently, *how* does this question relate to logic?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila You might want to refrain from the _ad hominem_ labelto live up to your preciously coveted "reputation". Also as a courtesy "we" expect that the community doesn't unilaterally belong to you when you start making assumptive gestures as "I expect" _ex cathedra_ It's not your or my forum, it's our forum. How does it NOT relate to logic? Wanna define "logic" for me with Goedelian rigor?

Comment: At any rate, I had enough of this oligarchial mafiosi like moderation. 

I leave you all with your self-patting badges to feel good about yourselves instead of seeing the broader picture how this innocuous question would actually benefit education and widening of knowledge.

So miopic. Sheesh.

Comment: @SniperClown: I have no idea what you want from me. I'm not sure you have either. I respectfully ask you not to use me to ventilate any bottled anger you have on other topics. Have a pleasant day.

Comment: Voted to reopen. What could be more clear than, "Is it possible to prove 2+2=4?" Several postings here have outlined how it is possible.

Comment: @Dan: Since you well understood this question. What is the language being used? Is $2$ part of the language, or is it a predecided shorthand for a term in the language, e.g. $S(S(0))$ or $1+1$ or $S(0)+S(0)$ or $S(0)\cdot S(S(0))$ or is it $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$ which itself is a bit of a "cheat"? Next, what is $4$? What is $+$, in case the language does not include $+$? Finally, what are the axioms concerned? Are we using set theory, field theory, Peano axioms, Modular Arithmetic, second-order arithmetic, group theory, ring theory? And don't get me started on inference rules.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The OP just wants to know if it possible to actually prove that 2+2=4 and to get some idea how you would go about it (without a lot of technical language). Why are you going on like this?

Comment: @Dan: Because mathematics is technical, as you may have noticed by now. And it is using a lot of fancy terms like "Peano axioms" and "first-order logic" vs. "second-order definitions" (which you have used and missed respectively in your answer), and whether or not $1,2,3,4$ and $+$ need to be defined at all. And so on and so forth. In hindsight I should have closed this one as a duplicate of one of the *several* $1+1=2$ threads which have comprehensive answers. In either case it's not clear at all what the OP wants to find out, or whether or not they are able to understand a proper answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The answer you give to a high school student is going to be different from one you would give to a professor of mathematics. Not everyone wants or needs the same level of detail in an answer. You have to use some judgement. I could have posted a link to a formal proof that was several hundred lines in length and the OP, in all likelihood, would have gotten nothing out of it.

Comment: @Logan: I don't agree that all the answers of mine you linked are similar, and the questions are not all similar either. Yes, there are some similarities, but some say outright that the OP has no knowledge; others are interested in a particular system; and another really just asks what qualifies as a theorem. I do not like being called a hypocrite and I have taken quite an offense from your comments. I hope that you will amass 3500 more answers, so you would see why sometimes you feel like closing questions similar to those you previously answered. I hope you have a lousy day. I'm out of here.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes I was having a bad day. Thanks for being the better man here.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 - Here's another one http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/2p2e4.html

Answer (score 37):

There are many ways of defining $\mathbb{N}.$ In the context of this question, the details aren't that important; what matters is that $\mathbb{N}$ ends up being a set equipped with a distinguished function $S : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and a distinguished element $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ subject to a theorem that says "definitions by recursion work." This allows us to prove the existence and uniqueness of a binary operation $+$ on $\mathbb{N}$ satisfying the following specifications.
$$n+0 = n, \quad n+S(m) = S(n+m)$$

Now write $4$ as shorthand for $S(S(S(S(0))))$ and write $2$ as shorthand for $S(S(0)).$ Then we have

$$2+2 = 2+S(S(0)) = S(2+S(0)) = S(S(2+0)) = S(S(2)) = S(S(S(S(0)))) = 4$$

**Extra Information.**

For completeness, here's several ways of defining the naturals.

1. The algebraic structure $\mathbb{N}$ can be defined as the sole (up to unique isomorphism) model of the Peano Postulates (which are second order).
2. It can also be defined as the free monounary algebra generated by the singleton set $\{0\}$ (I suggest googling this term if you do not know it).
3. Set theorists like defining it as the least set $\omega$ such that firstly, $\emptyset \in \omega,$ and secondly, $x \in \omega$ implies $x \cup \{x\} \in \omega$. The entity $\emptyset$ ends up being our $0$, and the function $x \mapsto x \cup \{x\}$ ends up being our successor function.

Comment: You could simply define $+$ as you suggest (as did Peano in the original version of his axioms) or you can prove the existence a unique binary function $+$ with the required properties using the rules of logic and set theory if you have them available.

Comment: While this is a good answer in itself, I think it's probably incomprehensible to the OP, who in particular may not know the words "isomorphism," "second order," or "recursion" or be able to read explanations of what a free monounary algebra is.

Comment: @KevinCarlson, you're right. I've reordered the information to emphasize what really matters.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Not to mention the use of notation. I hope the OP knows what $\mathbb{N}.$ means and what $S : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ means.

Answer (score 9):

The usual approach for formally proving that $2+2=4$ is to start from Peano's axioms (which define the set $N$  of natural numbers , $0\in N$ and a successor function on $N$). Using these axioms, along with the rules of logic and set theory, you can formally prove that there exists a unique binary function $+$ such that

> $x+0 = x$
>
> $x+(y+1) = (x+y)+1$

where $1$ is the successor of $0$, and $n+1$ is the successor of $n$.

This is a long and tedious process. (Earlier versions of Peano's axioms gave you the above definition to start.)

Then you define 2, 3 and 4 such that

> $2=1+1$
>
> $3=2+1$
>
> $4=3+1$

Then you have $2+2=2+(1+1)=(2+1)+1=3+1=4$

Comment: By "Peano's axioms" I mean the usual five axioms without $+$, i.e. *not* the first-order version which is more like Peano's original version of his axioms. I think you mean $1=S(0)$. Perhaps this is the source of your confusion.

Comment: You raise a legitimate point. I did leave out a few details for ease of reading, e.g. the implicit universal quantifiers, and the successor of $x$ being $x+1$, but I believe my definition is essentially correct.

Comment: This was not meant to be a formal proof. (I can supply one if you like, but it is several hundred lines long.) In the context of the OP, it is a stretch to say that my definition is somehow "misleading."

Answer (score 5):

We assume the Peano axioms.  Specifically:

> 1. Zero is a number.
> 2. If a is a number, the successor of a is a number.
>      (We denote the successor of $x$ as $x'$.)
> 3. Zero is not the successor of a number.
> 4. Two numbers of which the successors are equal are themselves equal.
> 5. (induction axiom.) If a set S of numbers contains zero and also the successor of every number in S, then every number is in S.

We then define addition recursively as follows:

> $$a+0 = a$$
>   $$a+b' = (a+b)'$$

Now, we will name some numbers.  We will denote:

> $$\begin{align}
> 0' &= 1 \\
> 1' &= 2 \\
> 2' &= 3 \\
> 3' &= 4
> \end{align}$$

We could keep going, but we only need to be able to denote the numbers $0$ through $4$ (inclusive).

Now, showing that $2+2 = 4$ is a simple application of the recursive formula for addition:
$$\begin{align}
2 + 2 &= 2 + 1' \\
&= (2+1)' \\
&= (2+0')' \\
&= ((2+0)')' \\
&= ((2)')' \\
&= 3'\\
&= 4
\end{align}$$

Comment: While (5) is true, it is not quite definitive.  I suggest phrasing it as (5*) "if $P(0)$ and $P(x) \rightarrow P(x')$ then $\forall x : P(x)$.  The difference can be seen by considering the following structure, let the domain $D$ be $\mathbb{N} \cup \{A, B, C\}$ and successor be extended by defining for $n$ in $\mathbb N$, $n* = n'$, also $A* = B, B* = C, C* = A$.  $\,\{\mathbb N, '\}$ satisfies both (5) and (5*), but $\{D, *\}$ satisfies (5) and not (5*) by taking $P(x)$ to be $x \in \mathbb N$.  Besides functionality, a purpose of the inductive axiom is to exclude structures like the above.

Answer (score 3):

The proposition "2+2 = 4" is a theorem of the Peano arithmetic (the five Peano's axioms). For example:
$$1 := 0',$$
$$2 := 1' = 0'',$$
$$3 := 2' = (1')' = 0''',$$
and so on.

Yes, it depends on to what meanings we assign "+" and the numerals.

Answer (score 2):

The most commonly used method to define sum in $\mathbb{N}$ is derived from Peano Axioms.

$0\in\mathbb{N}$ and $s:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$ is a given bijection, we can define $1:=s(0)$, $2:=s(1)$ and so on...

We can define a sum: $n+m:=s^{m}(n)$. In that case $2+2=s(s(2))=s(3)=4$. This sum satisfies the properties which we are accustomed.

Answer (score 0):

well this kind of proving depands on a set of axiom system of group like Z for example .
and these are axioms that been used to prove that 2+2=4

**Axiom 1. Algebraic Properties of Z (Properties of + and .)**

Properties of Addition

- A1. Associativity. For every x, y, and z in R, ( x + y ) + z = x + (
  y + z ).
- A2. Commutativity. For every x and y in R, x + y = y + x.
- A3. Identity. R contains an additive identity, 0, such that for every
  x in R,
                x+0=x.
- A4. Additive Inverses. For every x in R, there is an additive
  inverse, (-x ),
               in R such that x + (-x ) = 0.

**Axiom 2. Order Properties of Z (Properties of <)**

- (i ) Transitive Property. For every a, b, and c in Z, if a < b and b
  < c, then a < c.

  (ii ) Trichotomy Property. For every a and b in Z, exactly one of the
  following holds: a =b, a < b, or b < a.

  (iii ) Additive Property. For every a, b, and c in Z, if a < b, then
  a + c < b + c.

  (iv) Multiplicative Property. For every a, b, and c in Z, if a < b
  and 0 < c, then ac < bc.

  (v) Order of Identities. 0 < 1.

**Axiom 3. Th e Well-Ordering Principle**

- For any integer n, there is a next integer n + 1 that comes
  immediately after it, with no other integers in between.

with these sets of axioms you can easily prove  now that  2+2=4. just folow these steps

1+1=2

(1+1) + 1 =2+1 =3

(1+1+1)+1=3+1=4

hence

(1+1) +(1+1 )=2 +2 =4 done.